# How it possible in table td has different hights using one table

Tags: html, html-table

I want to design table in `html` that would have different heights of `td` using only one table. Is it possible? If possible how can I get it done?

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <td>height:30px</td>
        <td>height:90px</td>
        <td>height:60px</td>
        <td>height:80px</td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Something like this table :

[image]

Comment: The problem is, your "table" is not a table

Comment: use div tag arrangement that is better for you

Comment: Use div instead of table , as @MarkPerera mentioned, a this state  your table is not a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <style>
tr {
 height: auto;
 }
td {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: nowrap;
 vertical-align: top;
 background-color: #3399ff;
 height: 100%;
 width: 75px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 }
td:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #1177dd;
 }
 #b {
 height: 200px;
 }
 #j {
 height: 90px;
 }
 #k {
 height: 180px;
 }
 </style>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="b">b</td>
<td id="j">j</td>
<td id="k">k</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at rowspan. In my opinion, this is the best solution to your problem. It would take a slightly different HTML setup but should do the trick.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this should do the Trick:

```
<td style="height: 30px"></td>
```

For styling anything in html you have to use the style Tag and then what you want to style,
or link to a seperate `css` file

Comment: but by using this all tds have in same height i want different hights of td in one tr

Answer (score 0):

Use div inside the table td tag Or Convert all code to div  instead of table

```
<table>
        <tbody>
            <td><div "height:30"></div> <div "height:40"></div> <div "height:60">      </div></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```